# How to handle Multicolumn checkbox in react table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react table with multiple checkbox columns, if I check one column rest all are getting checked automatically, how to handle that. If I check first column checkbox only if has to be checked (One should not depend on other).
Here is my sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/tannerlinsley-react-table-row-selection-forked-3gcwm?file=/src/App.js:5923-5930

Comment: Please put in some code in the question so that we can help you.

Comment: I don't understand the desired behavior. What is the purpose of having a checkbox under both the name and info headers and how is what you want different than having both of those checked if either one is checked?

Comment: @CodeoftheWarrior - If I check the checkbox under "Name", then the checkbox under "Info" is also getting checked.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar , I have two checkbox columns one is at code : "Header: "Name2" and another is "Header: "Name1", I want those checkboxes to be independent (One should not depend on other) please see my sandbox repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `{...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()}` from line no. 213